# Does ScyllaDB optimize search of clustering key?

Tags: database, search, cassandra, nosql, scylla

I have a table with 3 clustering keys:

```
K1 K2 C1 C2 C3 V1 V2
```

Where `K1 & K2` are the partition keys, `C1, C2 and C3` are the clustering keys and `V1 and V2` are two value columns.

In this example, `C1, C2 and C3` represent the 3 coordinates of some shape (where each coordinate is a number from  1 to approx. 500). Each partition key in our table is linked to several hundred different values.

If I want to search for a row of `K1 & K2` that is has a clustering key equal to `C1 = 50, C2 = 450 and C3 = 250` how would Scylla execute this search assuming the clustering key is sorted from lowest to highest (ASC order)? Does Scylla always start searching from the beginning of the column to see whether a given key exists? In other words, I’m assuming Scylla will first search `C1` column for the value 50. If Scylla detects that we are at value 51+ and could not find C1 contains 50 it could stop searching the rest of the C1's column data since the data is sorted so there’s no way for the value 50 to appear after 51. In this case, it would not even need to check whether C2 contains the value 450 since we need all 3 clustering columns to match. If, however, C1 contains the value 50, it will move onto C2 and search (once again starting from the first entry of C2 column) whether C2 contains the value 450.

However, when C1 = 50 it would indeed be more efficient to start from the beginning. But when C2 = 450 (and the highest index = 500) it would be more efficient to start from the end. This is assuming Scylla “knows” the lowest / highest value for each of the clustering columns.

Does Scylla, in fact, optimize search in this fashion or does it take an entirely different approach?

Perhaps another way to phrase the question is as follows: Does it normally take Scylla longer to search for C1 = 450 vs. C1 = 50? Obviously, since we only have  a small dateset in this example the effect won’t be huge but if the dateset contained tens of thousands of entries the effect would be more pronounced.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Scylla has two data structures to search when executing a query on the replica:

- The in-memory data structure, used by row-cache and memtables
- The on-disk data structure, used by SStables

In both cases, data is organized on two levels: on the partition and row level. So Scylla will first do a lookup of the sought-after partition, then do a lookup of the sought-after row (by its clustering key) in the already looked-up partition.
Both of these data structures are sorted on both levels and in general the lookup happens via a binary search.

We use a btree in memory, binary search in this works as expected.

The SStable files include two indexes, an index, which covers all the partition found in the data file and a so called "summary", which is a sampled index of the index, this latter is always kept in memory in its entirety. Furthermore, if the partition has a lot of rows, the index will contain a so called "promoted index", which is a sampled index of the clustering keys found therein. So a query will first locate the "index-page" using a binary search in the in-memory summary. The index-page is the portion of the index file which contains the index entry for the sough-after partition. This index-page is then read linearly until the index-entry of interest is found. This gives us the start position of the partition in the data file. If the index entry also contains a promoted index, we can furthermore do a lookup in that to get a position closer to the start of said row in the data file. We then start parsing the data file at the position we got until the given row is found.

Note that clustering keys are not found one column at a time. A clustering key, regardless of how many components it has, is treated as a single value: a tuple of 1+ components. When a query doesn't specify all the components, an incomplete tuple called a "prefix" is created. This can be compared to other partial or full keys.